# How to perform checksum in PHP as in python?

Tags: php, python

I have a code in python, but I need to do the same in PHP, which I couldn't.

I have to perform checksum in php, but I have not been able to do it, in python the code works correctly, but in php I have not been able to do the check

This is the code in python:

```py
import hashlib
import sys

endUserId = "User123" #insert internal user ID here
applicationKey = "123456789123456789123456789" #insert application key here
applicationId = "1234" #insert App ID here.

checkSum = hashlib.md5(endUserId + applicationId + applicationKey)
userId = endUserId + "-" + applicationId + "-" + checkSum.hexdigest()[:10]
print(userId)
```

In PHP I have only been able to create an MD5 and choose the first 10 characters, but that does not help me, since I need the checksum as obtained in python.

```
<?php

$endUserId = "User123" //insert internal user ID here
$applicationKey = "123456789123456789123456789"; //insert application key here
$applicationId = "1234" //insert App ID here.

$hash = substr(md5($endUserId.'-'.$applicationId.'-'.$applicationKey), 0, 10);

$user_id = $endUserId.'-'.$applicationId.'-'.$hash;

<?
```

How can I perform checksum in php just like in the code above that is in python and get 10 characters?

Comment: The Python code hashes the values ***without "`-`" between them!***

Answer (score -1):

you can do this, I am not sure if you wanted first 10 or last 10 but the code below will help you
in case first 10 chars

```php
    $result = mb_substr($user_id, 0, 10);
```

in case last 10 char

```php
    $result = mb_substr($user_id, -10);
```

**make sure that you use a if statement to check the length of your string**

```php
    if(strlen($string) >= 10){
        //do awesome stuff
    }
```